# how to tell what cloud technology a site is using

Tags: cloud

I am not cheating or anything, but I have been asked 
"What cloud technolgy farmigo is using?"
and i need to answer it to apply for the software engineer position.
their site
http://www.farmigo.com/about/the-movement

and the jobs 
[developers.farmigo.com](http://developers.farmigo.com)

Now, I want to know any way how to know a site's technology (PHP, .NET)

so my question is :
 A generic algorithm to find out what technology a site is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using Google App Engine. I determined this by opening a shell and keying in `dig www.farmigo.com`. The CNAME DNS entry for www.farmigo.com is ghs.google.com. I know what cloud service Google offers, so the answer followed naturally.

And, to answer your question, there is not a "generic algorithm" for determining what cloud service a website is using. You have to do a little sleuthing.

Answer (score 0):

Browse their site. I found the following in the "terms" page, one click from home:

```
OPEN SOURCE
Farmigo.com uses open source software, including:
open-csv
google-gson
FreeMarker
gwt-fx
gwt-google-apis
Google Maps API
FileUpload
alive-pdf
ga-for-flash
jQuery
```

The best way to get more is detective work: from the job posting, you could probably reasonably assume that they have a Java stack (most likely servlet/Apache Tomcat based). Use what you know about their products/site to determine what technologies they might have on top of that: if they have large datasets or lots of very similar pages, they might have a use for Spring or Hibernate.

Deeper detective work options:

- Browse the Wayback machine for expired job postings looking for expertise in certain technologies.
- Ask: find a current or previous employee at the company (via their contact info, your recruitment point of contact, or linkedIn/similar) and ask what technologies they use.

If you want a truly formulaic way of determining what technologies a site uses, without having any backed access, try a vulnerability scanner. Note that this might or might not be legal.

Comment: hi zack, none iof the open source include cloud technology. I'll keep looking

Comment: and they are a start up- they don't have a way back :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just q quick note: If you are on windows (Joe Taylor used dig on linux) then use nslookup.
By the way, the question is a recruitment challenge for farmingo.com, no cheating!